# Should the linked questions section list closed questions?

Tags: support, questions

To the right of the question there is a section of linked questions.  Should that really include closed questions as well?  I find it awkward to see an interesting question and go to it, only to find that it is closed.  If it's not a good question, why publicize it?

Here is an example I hit today.  I was reading [When should I include information in my resume to indicate I have a high IQ?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21292/approaching-details-which-show-a-high-level-of-intelligence-on-the-cv/21305#21305) and saw the linked question

[image: side bar picture]

and I clicked on the one about a complex test, only to find it closed.
[image: title of closed question]

If we are supposed to improve the question so that it can be opened and answered, then having it in the list is appropriate.  If not, why even link it?  At  the least, it would be nice to know it is closed before bothering to click on it.

Comment: Related question: should closed questions or those put on hold be used to flag other similar questions as duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're supposed to be linked. They're closed, not deleted.

Personally, I find these very useful when following up on duplicates - the sidebar cross-links the original, those closed as duplicates, and any other questions closed or linked among them.